# In F#, how to write null to a Nullable<System.DateTime> class member?

Tags: f#, null

(Really Really confused).

I have a class, Visit, downloaded from a WCF service. It has a member defined as:

```
 public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> service_time
```

In F# Code, how is null written to this member? Or how to convert this C# class to F# record with Option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the member is writable, you can use `<-` to modify it, like this:

```
myObject.service_time <- Nullable DateTime.Now
```

To create a `Nullable` value without a value inside it, use its parameterless constructor:

```
myObject.service_time <- Nullable()
```

---

Judging by your questions, it looks like you're only just starting out and don't even have a good baseline from which to explore. If this is the case, I would recommend doing some reading first, and maybe doing some toy exercises, before trying to actually implement things. One source that I found particularly useful is [fsharpforfunandprofit.com](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/). Check it out.

Comment: As of F# 5 (released today) there’s improved Nullable interop. In particular automatic conversion: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#better-interop-with-nullable-value-types

Comment: @CaringDev F# 5 only just came out (yesterday), so the chances are low that the OP has it. Keeping in mind the fact that the OP is obviously very inexperienced and by their own admission "Really Really confused", I didn't want to confuse them any further.

Comment: Totally agree. However, SO should provide added value for other - more seasoned - developers too. And timezones  The blogpost has a nice example though.

Comment: Thanks to All... You definitely hit the nail on the head! Unfortunately, the books I have all focus on F# and don't highlight  very well how to mix C# code with F#, nor how to deal with .Net services (like WCF). Your criticisms are well taken and appreciated. (Good references would be most helpful). Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne there's an article about F#/C# interop on [fsharpforfunandprofit.com](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/completeness-seamless-dotnet-interop/) as well. But actually, this issue is not related to F#/C# interop at all. What's confusing you, I guess, is that F# doesn't implicitly convert types usually. The same goes for `int` to `float` (which means `double` in F#).